# Unable to call variable outside of function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im working on a node.js script and im unable to call a variable outside of the function. **File.name works perfectly** inside of the engine.on ready function, but will not function in the engine.on idle function.

```
engine.on('ready', function () {
  engine.files.forEach(function (file) {
    io.emit('chat message', "downloading " + file.name); 
    file.select()
  })

  engine.on('idle', function () {
    io.emit('chat message',"files '" + file.name + "' downloaded");
  });
});
```

How can i make the file.name a global variable that can be used throughout all of the functions?

Comment: just use: `var something =  file.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ready` function you have iteration over each file while in the `idle` you try to access only one file, this seems to be the cause of the error for me. I think the proper is not accessing only one, but all the files. It should look something like this:

```
engine.on('ready', function () {
  engine.files.forEach(function (file) {
    io.emit('chat message', "downloading " + file.name); 
    file.select()
  }
});

engine.on('idle', function () {
  engine.files.forEach(function (file) {
    io.emit('chat message', "files '" + file.name + "' downloaded); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
global['fileName'] = file.name;
```

or set your whole file globaly:

```
global['file'] = file;
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable file is defined within the function invoked in the forEach loop and it refers to an individual file. I think what you want to do is loop through the files that have been downloaded when the engine goes idle. You might also want to add some marker or keep an index of which files have already been printed and only print the files downloaded since the most recent idle. But, here's an example where you could output all the files that have been downloaded when the engine goes idle.

```js
engine.on('ready', function () {
    engine.files.forEach(function (file) {
        io.emit('chat message', "downloading " + file.name);

        file.select();
    });
    engine.on('idle', function () {
        engine.files.forEach(function (file) {
            io.emit('chat message', "files '" + file.name + "' downloaded");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `engine.on('idle', function () {` function does not have access to the `file` object as the `file` object only exists inside of your `forEach` loop. You will need to have a look at what arguments get passed to `engine.on('idle')` to see what parameters are available.